# Installation Problem with spdlog when using Drake in CMake Project

Tags: drake

I was trying to use drake in my project, however, I keep getting this problem with `spdlog`

```bash
In file included from /home/bolun/Documents/spdlog/install/include/spdlog/spdlog.h:12,
                 from /opt/drake/include/drake/common/text_logging.h:85,
                 from /path/to/file.cpp:1:
/home/bolun/Documents/spdlog/install/include/spdlog/common.h:181:30: error: ‘format_string’ in namespace ‘fmt’ does not name a template type
  181 | using format_string_t = fmt::format_string<Args...>;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/bolun/Documents/spdlog/install/include/spdlog/common.h:190:33: error: ‘basic_runtime’ in namespace ‘fmt’ does not name a template type
  190 | using fmt_runtime_string = fmt::basic_runtime<Char>;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/bolun/Documents/spdlog/install/include/spdlog/common.h:200:66: error: ‘fmt_runtime_string’ was not declared in this scope
  200 |                                  std::is_same<remove_cvref_t<T>, fmt_runtime_string<Char>>::value> {
      |                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/bolun/Documents/spdlog/install/include/spdlog/common.h:200:85: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  200 |                                  std::is_same<remove_cvref_t<T>, fmt_runtime_string<Char>>::value> {
      |                                                                                     ^~~~
/home/bolun/Documents/spdlog/install/include/spdlog/common.h:200:98: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘>’ token
  200 |                                  std::is_same<remove_cvref_t<T>, fmt_runtime_string<Char>>::value> {
      |                                                                                                  ^
/home/bolun/Documents/spdlog/install/include/spdlog/common.h: In function ‘constexpr spdlog::string_view_t spdlog::details::to_string_view(const memory_buf_t&)’:
/home/bolun/Documents/spdlog/install/include/spdlog/common.h:347:42: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘const T* fmt::v5::internal::basic_buffer<T>::data() const [with T = char]’
```

I tried installing `spdlog`'s newest version and also using the one I installed from `apt`, however, none of them solved this issue.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: We will need a lot more information before we can help. Please update your question with more details: (1) Which of the https://drake.mit.edu/installation.html methods are you trying to use? (2) A list of commands you ran and their output, or the https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples project you tried that didn't work.

Comment: And (3) which OS distribution you're using (e.g., "Ubuntu 22.04").

Answer (score 0):

Seeing `/home` in the output makes me think you're using Ubuntu, not macOS.

Seeing `/opt/drake/include/drake/` in the output makes me think you're using https://drake.mit.edu/apt.html to install Drake.

The debian package `drake-dev` declares `Depends:` on the debian package `libspdlog-dev`, which provides the spdlog headers and that package declares the correct dependency on fmt.

In short -- if you are using apt to install a binary release of Drake, then you should not install spdlog manually, nor should you have any other build of spdlog on the CMake search path beyond the spdlog that's in `/usr/include`.